# MongoDB - How to get a date that is between two dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I am creating a database for a dentist. On Tuesdays, the secretary sends reminders to all the patients who have an appointment for the next week.

The query I used in SQL is:

```
SELECT P.Name    
    , P.Tel_No    
    , A.Appointment_Time    
    , A.Appointment_Date    
FROM Patient AS P    
    INNER JOIN Booking AS B ON P.Patient_ID = B.Patient_ID    
    INNER JOIN Appointment AS A ON B.Appointment_ID = A.Appointment_ID    
WHERE A.Reminder_Sent = 0  
AND A.Appointment_Date BETWEEN     
    ADDDATE(DAY, 6, CURDATE()) AND ADDDATE(DAY, 9, CURDATE());
```

I want to follow the same logic as the last two lines. So Tuesday plus 6 days is the following Monday, and Tuesday plus 9 days is the following Friday. If the appointment falls between these two dates, then a reminder is sent.

How do I extend this logic to MongoDB?

I imagine it would be something like:

```
"Appointment Time" : $range{

{$dateAdd:{currentdate(),unit:day,amount:6}, 

{$dateAdd:{currentdate(),unit:day,amount:9}}
```

Or something like this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Such queries are called as "Date Range Queries". MongoDB Manual has such examples with same title

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$$NOW](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.NOW) variable, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gt: [
              "$Appointment_Date",
              {
                $add: [
                  "$$NOW",
                  518400000 // 6 days in miliseconds
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            $lt: [
              "$Appointment_Date",
              {
                $add: [
                  "$$NOW",
                  777600000 // 9 days in miliseconds
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I9nHtJGHTXj)

If you're using Mongo version 5+ this query can be simplified by using [$dateAdd](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/), I just assumed you're not on such an advanced version.